# Add and show object in JList

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I am working on a project where I am supposed to create an application that takes information and stores it in a JList, and when I select the name of a person in the JList it should then show the contact information of that person.
I have made 2 classes - one of them in the contact class and the other is the one with the JFrame.

This is the Contact class

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phNumber;
private String address;


public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String phNumber, String address) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phNumber = phNumber;
    this.address = address;
}


public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}


public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}


public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}


public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


public String getPhNumber() {
    return phNumber;
}


public void setPhNumber(String phNumber) {
    this.phNumber = phNumber;
}


public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}


public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if(((Contact) o).getFirstName().compareTo(this.firstName)>=1){
        return 1;
    }
    if(((Contact) o).getFirstName().compareTo(this.firstName)<=-1){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


}
```

Then this is the code for the add button I am working on.

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Save");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "serial" })
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String f = txtFirst.getText();
            String l = txtLast.getText();
            String p = txtPhone.getText();
            String a = txtAddress.getText();

            list.add(new Contact(f, l, p, a));

            Object[] array = list.toArray();
            //listView is the name of the JList
            listView.setListData((Contact[]) array);

        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(244, 153, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
```

I just need help adding the Contact class into the JList and that be able to display the the first and last name on the JList
Thank you for helping me in advance

Comment: What is `list`? Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here. See also [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: list is an arrraylist

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your Contact object to the JList and then create a custom renderer.

Something like:

```
class ContactRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index,
        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value,
            index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        Contact contact = (Contact)value;
        setText(contact.getFirstName() + " " + contact.getLastName()


        return this;
    }
}
```

You assign the renderer to the Jlist using:

```
list.setCellRenderer( new ContactRenderer() );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Creating a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more information and examples. The example renderer is for a combo box, but the concept is the same.